# UIGestureRecognizer in objective-C++

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c++

I want to know the `UIGestureRecognizer` working or not in Objective-C++ because i've implemented this one but **tap** method never calling. So please let me know is it possible or not in Objective-C++.

```
        - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)];
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dharm"];
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
    imgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UITapGestureRecognizer* tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [imgView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
}    
    - (void)tap:(id)sender {
        NSLog(@"Tap Pressed");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `[imgView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];`